# C# SMTP sends email with empty body in productive enviroment

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, gmail

I'm working on a project that needs to send an invitation email to an email specified by the user.
I'm using C#, SMTP and the body is an html template.

If I try, Locally there is no problem, I can send emails and everything works as intended, I receive the email with the correct template.

[image: Email sent locally]

The problem comes when I'm trying to send the email from the productive environment, from there the email received is with the empty body and no traces of the body template.

[image: Email with empty body sent from the productive enviroment]

This is the code I'm using to send the email.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(Configuration["EmailFrom"],to);
msg.Subject = subject;
msg.Body = this.emailBody;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(Configuration["SMTP"], Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["PORT"]));
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Configuration["EmailFrom"], Configuration["PasswordEmailFrom"]);
smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

Now, I know the productive enviroment is hosted in a AWS server, but don't know the configuration of the server or if it has something to do with the problem.

The templates are using divs instead of tables in some cases but i think is an unrelated issue, so I really don't know where the problem could be.

**Edit:**
I grab the info i will use to replace from the database and grabbing the template from a local HTML file hosted in the server. 
This is the code where it sets the email template and replace the content:

```
EmailService sendDriverInvitation = new EmailService(_env);

sendDriverInvitation.setEmailTemplate($"ClientApp/{AssetsDirectory}/assets/emailTemplates/InvitationDriver.html");

sendDriverInvitation.emailBody = sendDriverInvitation.emailBody.Replace("[DER Name]", userName).Replace("[Company Name]", DbaName);
sendDriverInvitation.sendMail(email, "Invitation Email");
```

And this is the code for setEmailTemplate:

```
HTMLReader reader = new HTMLReader();

string htmlCompleteTemplatePath = Path.Combine(webRoot, htmlTemplatePath);
this.emailBody = reader.ReadHtmlFile(htmlCompleteTemplatePath);
```

Comment: How is `emailBody` being set?

Comment: Since all the sending part seems to work, the problem is more likely to be found in the part where `this.emailBody` is being built. Are you retrieving data from a database and try-catch all errors there leaving your body empty?

Comment: Write `msg.Body` to your logging system to see what the value is.  My guess would be there is a template file which is missing from production. I would hope there is a message in your logs somewhere saying 'email template file missing'.

Comment: I edited the question with more info about how I'm setting the `this.emailBody` variable